# Log message when Object is being deallocated with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Is there a way to log (check) an object is deallocated when using ARC?

Pre-ARC I often found it useful to do:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    NSLog(@"MyObject deallocating");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - simply remove

```
[super dealloc];
```

and everything will compile and run as expected.

ARC compiler inserts the call to `super dealloc` automatically, and prohibits explicit use of `dealloc` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dealloc method under ARC. Just remove the call to super. Your current code will work like this:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"MyObject deallocating");
}
```